# The function describe() from pandas can't work in my code ,is csv isn't dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The function describe() can't work and when I run the code ,it can't generate  any ouput, but info() is working.

I use these command to get my data.csv form Iris,data

```sh
Jason@X1:~/flower/Dat$ echo  sepal length,sepal width,\
> petal length,petal width,class > data.csv
Jason@X1:~/flower/Data$ cat Iris.data | cut -d',' -f 1,2,3,4,5 >> data.csv
Jason@X1:~/flower/Data$ xdg-open data.csv
```

Ubuntu 18.04

python3

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import Series,DataFrame

data_train=pd.read_csv('/home/jason/Documents/ML/flower/Data/data.csv')
data_train # none output
data_train.info() # output
data_train.describe() # none output
```

I hope it can output something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using :-

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import Series,DataFrame

data_train=pd.read_csv('/home/jason/Documents/ML/flower/Data/data.csv')
print(data_train) # none output
print(data_train.info()) # output
print(data_train.describe()) # none output
```

If you want to use only `data_train` to print train values then you should use `jupyter notebook` or python shell.

Comment: @金正旭 Appreciate the work by upvoting and accepting the solution if it's works.

Comment: 金正旭, If this answer helped you, please accept this as the correct answer. Thanks.